# using mvc Ajax How to transfer values from clientside to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here I'm new to Ajax please Guide me How to bind vaues from .cshtml to .cs Here i'm using Mvc with Jquery Ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnSubmit').click(function () {

                var fname = $('#fname').val();
                var Lname = $('#Lname').val();

            if (fname.length > 0 && Lname.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/HitAjax',
                    type: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(),

                })
            }

        })
    })
</script>
```

**Htmlcoding**

```
 <div>
        <div>
           <input type="text" id="fname" name="FirName" class="form-control" />
           <input type="text" id="Lname" name="LatName" class="form-control" />
    <input type="button" id="BtnSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

**MvcController**

```
 public ActionResult HitAjax(string FirName, string LatName)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
          url: '/Home/HitAjax',
          type: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          data: {FirName:fname , LatName:Lname },
          success: function(data)
            {
             //Blah Blah
            }
            })


var myData = {
           FirstName: fname,
           Last name: lname,
           //All the fields goes here
           }
```

Then u can pass that like this,

```
data:myData,
```

See in this case your action method should have a parameter like

```
myAction(UrClass myData)`
{
 }
```

Comment: If i have 1000 values then what i can I need to pass 1000 values in data:{-----}

Comment: Could not understand why down voted. U have already mentioned in ur questions only 2 value. If u want to pass 1000 value then u need to create an object and pass it.

Comment: could  u please mention how to create an object

Comment: blue t shirts that u  & u from Buwaneshwar